# Does sklearn time cpu time or wall time

Tags: python, time, scikit-learn, cpu

Are the returned timing values for the random and grid search implementations of sklearn in CPU or wall time? All I can find in the documentation is the following:

> The mean_fit_time, std_fit_time, mean_score_time and std_score_time
>   are all in seconds.

So I am assuming that would mean wall time as the default, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L1154)...

Line 748:

```py
self.cv_results_ = results
```

Okay, what is `results`?

Line 706:

```py
results = self._format_results(
          all_candidate_params, scorers, n_splits, all_out)
return results
```

Okay, what is `all_out`?

Line 703:

```py
all_out.extend(out)
```

and then `out` is:

Line 682:

```
out = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_score)(clone(base_estimator),
```

and `_fit_and_score` is imported from `sklearn.model_selection._validation.py` so we look in [there](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841d57e8b5f6b2a570312e9d832e69debc/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py)...

Line 543:

```py
fit_time = time.time() - start_time
```

Aha! There we go. It's wall time, as `Python`'s `time.time()`[gives you the current Unix time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html).